# JAX-RS @Path annotation with regular expression doesn't match expected URL

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I want the URL for my API to have following format for users resource:

```
http://hostname/webappname/something/something/serviceName/orgs/{id}/users
```

However, I get a 404 error as the URL mapping fails. But if I have following format, I get the response.

```
http://hostname/webappname/{id}/something/something/serviceName/orgs/{id}/users
```

This is my `@Path` annotation:

```
@Path("/orgs/{oid: [0-9]+}/users")
```

But if I have the following `@Path` annotation:

```
@Path("/orgs")
```

With URL's

```
http://hostname/webappname/{id}/something/something/serviceName/orgs
http://hostname/webappname/something/something/serviceName/orgs
```

I always get a response back. Can someone tell how should I provide `@Path` annotation for my resource. Or where am I going wrong?

Users Resource class looks like this:

```
    @Path("/orgs/{oid: [0-9]+}/users")
    @Component
    public class UserResource extends Resource {

    }
```

Orgs Resource class looks like this:

```
    @Path("/orgs")
    @Component
    public class OrgResource extends Resource {

    }
```

Comment: It might help if you POST portions of your resource class. Including the @Path annotations at the class and method level. Are you using sub-resource locators?

Comment: I added portions of Resource classes. I have sub-resources under the class level path annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It had nothing to do with the my @Path annotation. While creating this project I added some old code dependencies. One of then was unsharding filter whose job was to strip of shard present in the URL before passing it to the next filter. It was removing the {oid} from the requested path and hence there was a URL mapping error. I faced this issue only when I changed the URL format for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [JAX-RS subresources](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Resource_Locators_and_Sub_Resources.html). In your case, `UserResource` is a subresource of `OrgResource`.